# How can I tag parent list items to child list

Tags: android, listview

How can it be possible to tag parent list items to child list by that if i select the child item have to disable the parent list item . please help me am new to android.

activity :

This is my activity where i click on parent list item i will get dialog with child list .

```
listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    listView1.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                       int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            newListitems2.clear();
            newListitems2.addAll(itemsList1);

            // ArrayList newListitems2 = new ArrayList();
            //newListitems2.add(itemsList1);
            dialog = new Dialog(PendingOrdersActitvity.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.itembumping);
            dialog.show();

            listView1.setTag(position);
            list1 = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.list1);

            ItemBumpingAdapter adapter2 = new ItemBumpingAdapter(PendingOrdersActitvity.this, newListitems2);
            list1.setAdapter(adapter2);


            Button okButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ok1);
            okButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    dialog.dismiss();

                }
            });
            Button cancelButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.Cancel1);
            cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }


            });
            return true;

        }
    });
```

parent list Adapter :

where parent list loads

Child adapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    String item = null, qty = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.itembumpingadapter, null);
        holder.qty = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.qty);
        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item);
        holder.childText = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.childitem);
        holder.qtyChild = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.qtychild);
        holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chckbox1);
        convertView.setTag(holder);


    } else {

        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    parentobjid = newListitems.get(position).getParentobjectid();
    if (!parentobjid.isEmpty()) {
        holder.name.setText("   " + newListitems.get(position).getItemnNameDisplay());
        holder.name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#CC0000"));
        holder.qty.setText("      " + String.valueOf(newListitems.get(position)
                .getQuantityDisplay()));
        holder.qty.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#CC0000"));
    } else {

        holder.name.setText(newListitems.get(position).getItemnNameDisplay());
        holder.qty.setText(String.valueOf(newListitems.get(position)
                .getQuantityDisplay()));
        holder.name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        holder.qty.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        holder.checkbox.setChecked(false);

        holder.checkbox.setTag(position);

        holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int pos = (Integer) v.getTag();
                newListitems.get(pos).setChecked(!newListitems.get(pos).isChecked());

            }

        });
        if (newListitems.get(position).isChecked()) {
            holder.name.setEnabled(true);
            holder.name.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DCDBDB"));


        } else {
            holder.name.setEnabled(false);
        }


    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Find parent from child and disable it

Comment: my problem is that only how can i find parent by clicking on child\

Comment: so how can I understand what widget you use from this question. Do you see now why you get downvotes?.. Look at child DNA or edit question and give more information

Comment: i will edit ques with code please check it

Comment: tnq for ur response and suggestion

Comment: I edited question please see it

Comment: you can find my email on my profile page.

Comment: haa k tnq so much i will ping u now in mail

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ExpandableListView` if you have a child list to a parent list. If you are not familiar with it check [this link](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/) to learn more.

There is an `OnChildClickListener` provided by `ExpandableListView` which when clicked gives you both, child's position and parents's position:

```
// Listview on child click listener
expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)
                            + " : "
                            + listDataChild.get(
                                    listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(
                                    childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: I will edit question with code or if ur willing i will mail u

Comment: tnq for ur response